# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'builtin_function_or_method' objects in python

Tags: python, twitter

Please I am beginner in python coding.This is my code and am not able to resolve the error . Can some one suggest me what is the prob in code actually. thanks in advance.

```
import urllib2
username = '<YOUR USERNAME>'
password = '<YOUR PASSWORD>'
format = 'json' # json or xml
filename = 'archive.json' # filename of the archive
tweets = 164 # number of tweets
pages = (int(float(tweets)/float(80)))+1
auth = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
auth.add_password(None, 'http://twitter.com/account/', username, password)
authHandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(auth)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener) 
i = 1
response = ''
print 'Downloading tweets. Note that this may take some time'
while i <= pages:
    request = urllib2.Request('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/account.' \
    + format + '?page=' + str(i))
    response = response + urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    i = i + 1
handle = open(filename,"w")
handle.write(response)
handle.close()
print 'Archived ' + str(tweets) + ' of ' + username + \
'\'s tweets to ' + filename
```

ERROR is like this below:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 3, in <module>
    + format + '?page=' + str(i))
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'builtin_function_or_method' objects**
```

Comment: `format` is a built-in function. Sure you reassigned it to a string? The best solution would be to use another variable name.

Comment: i did that but its showing me the error specified below...Unauthorized 401 kind of.

Comment: this is entirely unrelated, but the error is pretty self-explanatory. Try to debug it yourself and if you run into problems, open a new question for that with a minimal, self-contained code sample that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`format` is a built-in function. The error you quote is exactly what you get if you try to use `+` with the built-in `format` and a string.

Your earlier assignment `format = 'json'` should have shadowed the built-in function. But your error trace indicates that you're running this from some sort of shell, and not actually executing the code as you have posted it. So without knowing what exactly is executing, my guess is your assignment to `format` isn't in effect, for whatever reason.

Comment: thank you.The prob was with "format" only. the error now i am getting is :

Comment: File "<pyshell#17>", line 4, in <module>
    response = response + urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Comment: @KeerthanTantry When you get a HTTP error code, google it. They are very well known. In this case the one-word description in the error message itself is pretty clear: Unauthorized. Then try adding some debug statements to your program to see what URL it's actually requesting, and try putting that into a browser to see if gets the same error response. Probably you will, and your script has simply generated the wrong URL; hopefully you can tell that by looking at it.

Comment: @KeerthanTantry I've never used twitter's API, so I have no idea how to help you with the specifics of that. But Stack Overflow isn't really an interactive debugger anyway; you'll make much more headway if you debug the problem yourself, and ask the specific questions that come up. Posting code and error messages and simply asking "what's wrong" is a very inefficient way to use SO.